# Insert Date in a cell based on a string in another cell vba

Tags: vba, excel, date

if there are 5 columns in an spreadsheet. 
A1=S.No B1=Order number C1=Status D1=IQ Created Date E1=Sent mail to manager date

Status column will have dropdown list --> 1) IQ Pending 2) Waiting for manager response 3)Inbound delay 4)Others.

**Requirement:** If the Status column is set to "IQ Pending", then automatically excel should insert that day's date in column "IQ Created Date". Like wise, If the Status column is set to "Waiting for manager response", then automatically excel should insert that day's date in column "Sent mail to manager date"

Answer (score 0):

Two simple formulas will answer your question, I hope:
type "=IF(C2="IQ Pending", TODAY())" in Cell D2, and
type "=IF(C2="Waiting for manager response",TODAY())" in Cell E2.

You can change the second line to 
"If(C2<>"", TODAY())
Which will ensure that no matter what text your C2 cell contains, you will have your Date in D2, if that's what you want.

Comment: Hello @Vasant, thanks for your response. But, if we change the status to from "IQ Pending" to something else, the date in "IQ Created Date" is going of. The date should be there even if status is changed.